# IE <= 9 pseudo element inherits container style when container is hovered

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3mdc/2/) for a working example of the problem.
Opera 12, chrome, and firefox all work as intended, while IE9 and below underline the pseudo element.

I have already tried the following:

```
a:hover *,
a:before,
a:hover:before {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

but neither selectors work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to find an (half decent) way to handle IE:

```
clip: rect(0px 300px 16px 0px);
```

This hides the underline while leaving everything else - also updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Razor/m3mdc/6/)